# What are the issues with quote only answer?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I found a question that I can answer. Since I am not good in phrasing statements in English, I can answer it using only the quote from a credible source.

Why such answers are discouraged?

If no, can I just provide the reference and the quote to answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer can quote a statement or excerpt from another source or author, but it's a good idea to explain **why** you're quoting that excerpt or statement, and you should make it clear that you're quoting something, otherwise, it could be considered **plagiarism**, which is at least discouraged, and your answer can be deleted (as explained [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)).

To quote something, make sure to precede it with `>` (explained [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)), and provide the name of the source/author (and ideally also the link to it, especially if freely available). This is explained well [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), but I think you're already familiar with this.

An example of my answers where I thought that quoting would have been a good idea is [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/23427/2444), but *note that* I didn't just quote the book, but I also tried to answer the question **specifically** based on my interpretation of that quote and knowledge, and I also tried to explain why I am quoting the book. In this case, I was also more or less familiar with the topic, so I am relatively sure that my interpretation of the excerpt (but not just that, because that specific answer was also based on my knowledge of the topic) and specific answer are correct.

A quote-only answer may also be discouraged because I think we want to be a source of original content (which doesn't necessarily mean "original science", otherwise, you may just try publishing your new findings on a journal or conference proceedings; in any case, note that, in most cases, I came up with answers and solutions that I didn't find elsewhere; sometimes, you can find the partial answer to your question in a book or on the web, but not the *full* answer; for example, in [this case](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28566/2444), I really tried to make the full derivation, but, without my previous knowledge of the topic, probably, I would not have been able to do it). I am not sure if this is a policy, but I think it's pretty clear that, if we all just copied from other sources, there would be no reason for us to exist (you can just search for your answer elsewhere).